# How can I reach to the two values added and created with generic class list

Tags: java, arrays, list, generics, nested

How can I reach to the two values added and created with generic class list? I've created a generic class with 2 variable (tag_id) and (rssi).

**Generic Class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Data
public class Test<T>{

    public int tag_id;

    public float rssi;

    public List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public Test() {
    
    }
}
```

**RFID Class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Data
public class RFID extends Test {
    public RFID(float rssi) {
        this.rssi = rssi;
    }
```

**Tag Class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Data
public class Tag extends Test {

    public Tag(int tag_id) {
        this.tag_id = tag_id;
    }
```

**Main Class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Test> testlist = new ArrayList<>();
            testlist.add(new Tag(1));
            testlist.add(new RFID(1));
    }
```

I want to output like this: `[1(tag_id), [1.0,2.0,3.0](rssi)]`. I can reach the two values, but not the nested type and I can add values to my testlist, but I want to output nested type.

Comment: What does it mean, nested type? your question is not clear. all more details

Comment: Just i want a output like [1, [1.0,2.0,3.0]] tag_id is left side and rssi value(float) at right side i want a output just like this.

Comment: Generics do not really exist, they are just for compilation checks. In your runtime, your instances are truly of their original object types, so you can use `instanceof`, or just override `toString()` in each class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add multiple RFID for single Tag write your code as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Demo3Application.class, args);

    List<Test> testlist = new ArrayList<>();
    testlist.add(new Tag(1));
    testlist.get(0).list.add(new RFID(1));
    testlist.get(0).list.add(new RFID(66));

    testlist.add(new Tag(2));
    testlist.get(1).list.add(new RFID(2));
    testlist.get(1).list.add(new RFID(77));

    for (Test test: testlist) {
        System.out.println("[" + test.getTag_id() + ", [" + test.getList().stream().map(i -> String.valueOf(i)).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) + "]]");
    }
}
```

Comment: The output is;
[1, [RFID(), RFID()]]
[2, [RFID(), RFID()]]
Can i see at output like this ? 
[1, [RFID(1), RFID(66)]]
[2, [RFID(2), RFID(77)]]